# UITableView: user interaction with section's footer

Tags: uitableview, scroll, footer, interaction

For one of UITableView sections I have put a view with a UIDatePicker into it's footer (using tableview:viewForFooterInSection:). The problem is that UIDatePicker receives only single touch events (tapping) and doesn't receive scroll events, so I am unable to set appropriate time inside it. Instead of scrolling UIDatePicker's hours or minutes spinners, UITableView scrolls.

How can I make UIDatePicker respond to user "drag" events and make it spin instead of scrolling UITableView?

Comment: It seems that iOS 2.x had problems with scrollviews inside scrollviews.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView footerView with button, button doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989740/uitableview-footerview-with-button-button-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 2 had problems with scrollviews inside scrollviews. Same thing works fine on iOS 3+.

Answer (score -1):

You can subclass `UITableViewCell` and then add `UIDatePicker` view as a subview on that subclassed `UITableViewCell`. Then you will get the way your requirement is.

As example.

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];  
[self addSubview:datePicker];  
[datePicker release];
```

Here self refers to `UITableViewCell` subclass object.