# UITableView footerView with button, button doesn't work

Tags: iphone, uitableview, footer

I'm trying to create a custom view for my UITableView footerView that has a button in it.  I can see it there, but when I touch it, nothing happens... can you see what's wrong here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(self.tableView.tableFooterView == nil) {
        //allocate the view if it doesn't exist yet
        UIView *footerView  = [[UIView alloc] init];

        //create the button
        UIButton *addNewBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];     
        //the button should be as big as a table view cell
        [addNewBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [AddMerchantTVC cellHeight])];

        //set title, font size and font color
        [addNewBtn setTitle:@"Add New" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [addNewBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
        [addNewBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [addNewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addNew:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UIImageView *cellGradient = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellGradient.png"]];
        cellGradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 54, 320, 16);
        [footerView addSubview:cellGradient];

        //add the button to the view
        [footerView addSubview:addNewBtn];
        footerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
        self.tableView.tableFooterView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [footerView release];
        [cellGradient release];
}

- (void)addNew:(id)sender {
    // This is never called
    NSLog(@"Touched.");
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're not setting the footerView's frame.  Set the frame of the footerView to be at least as high as the button otherwise the touches don't get passed down to the button.

Comment: This worked for me when I implemented `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
` to specify the footer height.

Answer (score 7):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50.0f;
}
```

put this method in your class your problem will solve.....

Answer (score 2):

its worked for me i just add

```
footerView.frame =CGRectMake(0, 300, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the tableView's **sectionFooterHeight** property before the call to **viewForFooterInSection** occurs (can't do it inside the viewForFooterInSection method).

Comment: Especially if you use XIB to build your UIView, you need to implement this function

Answer (score -9):

Create a subclass of UIView and include these methods:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Do I really need a subclass of UIView to accomplish this?  If so, that is annoying.