# UISegmentedControl not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm adding a UISegmentedControl to the foot of a grouped UITableView programmatically. It's showing up fine, but when I tap on any of the options, they don't highlight. What am I doing wrong here? Also, how do I set a default item to be highlighted?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set up cacheControl
    NSArray* cacheDays = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
    self.cacheControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:cacheDays];
    [self.cacheControl setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.cacheControl addTarget:self action:@selector(cacheSelection:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.cacheControl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 16, self.tbl.frame.size.width-20, 47);
    [self.cacheControl setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];

}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:{
            UIView* footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tbl.frame.size.width, tbl.contentInset.top)];
            footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            return footerView;
        }
        case 1:{
            UIView* footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tbl.frame.size.width, 16)];
            footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            [footerView setClipsToBounds:NO];

            [footerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
            [footerView addSubview:self.cacheControl];

            return footerView;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Screenshot, as requested:

[image: Settings-screen]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: This answer from a similar question fixed it for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12436632/107821

Comment: Try setting clipsToBounds to YES, and see if the segmented control still appears (to make sure it's actually within the bounds of your view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a default item, do: `[cacheControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0]` with the index that you want selected.

Comment: I asked two questions. I found the answer to my first (I aded a comment) and this does answer the second.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `-tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` from the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

This will let the table view adjust the height of the section footer to fit your view and allow it to receive user interactions.